# how to start A activity after finish old A activity

Tags: android

I tried to set `intent.setFlags (FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`, but the effect is not as I think.

It will execute onResume () in the old A activity.

But I want the effect as shown below:

> A activity onCreate() ... onPause()
>
> anywhere(from notification, from B activity ...) start A activity again
>
> old A activity onDestory()
>
> create new A activity

Comment: Have you add android:launchMode="singleTop" in AndroidManifest.xml for your activity A. And update your view by overriding  onNewIntent()

Comment: Before starting Activity A again, check if activity A is existing if it is existing finish() Activity A and then start new activity

Comment: @JRamesh  
It execute onResume () in the old A activity too.

Comment: @Yatish Thank you for the idea, I think I can change the original behavior, when the notification is clicked, open another activity to determine whether to close the old A activity to meet my needs

Answer (score 0):

use (FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag when u passing intent. then after startactivity() use finish() method.

Comment: It execute onResume () in the old A activity too.

Comment: then if i am right u want to call activity a again from activity b but not same as privious...try this use finish() method from activity a to activity b   Intent i = new Intent(Activity_1.this, Activity_2.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i); finish();

Comment: because i want user can view original state when he click history to start A activity. but i have notification to let user click it to start A activity(need to be initialized in accordance with the new bundle). so i want to start A activity from anywhere like notification can finish old activity. but I tried many of the flag all unable to meet my needs.

Comment: yes get it it will happen just use finish() method when ever u callin startactivity ...did you try it?

Comment: I refer to Yatish's advice. I set up a B activity as the starting point for the click notification, and in the B activity check whether there is an old A activity, if it exists, then turn off A and then open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)**

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

SAMPLE CODE

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, OTHERACTIVITY.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```